# Row by column dot product in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays (A, B) of equal dimensions lets say 3*3 each. I want to have an output vector of size (3,) that has the dot product of the first row of A and first column of B, second row of A and second column of B and so on.

```
    A = np.array([[ 5, 1 ,3], [ 1, 1 ,1], [ 1, 2 ,1]])
    B = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])
```

What I want to have as result is *[16,6,8]* which would be equivilant to

```
    np.diagonal(A.dot(B.T))
```

but of course I don't want this solution because the matrix is very large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do an element wise multiplication and then `sum` the rows:

```
(A * B).sum(axis=1)
# array([16,  6,  8])
```

Or use `np.einsum`:

```
np.einsum('ij,ij->i', A, B)
# array([16,  6,  8])
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the second solution